# "story" without article meaning "past"

Tags: word-usage, word-in-context, word-meaning

Some dictionaries say that the word "story" as a general noun means "past, past event, part of what was before". Does it mean we can use it abstractly to mean "history, what is past" without an article?
For instance:

- Those ideas are story now.

Edit: I did a Google search and Google books check but didn't find any relevant examples of such usage, still I am eager to know if it is anyway possible to use "story" in place of "history" to describe something which is now past.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a mishearing / mistranscription - ***story*** for ***history***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't mishear or mistranscript, I'm no that dumb. I know what "history" means, I particularly asked about "story" in the same sense or meaning.

Comment: I see two people have seen fit to upvote your comment, but it cuts no ice with me. You cite the usage as a "for instance", but provide no meaningful evidence that your example actually occurs in the real world. FWIW I've just searched Google Books for [*are story now*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22are+story+now%22), which returns just 7 hits. Of which the only one where I can read the context is some Filipino poet. Compare that to 2,370 hits for [*are **history** now*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22are+history+now%22).

Comment: It would probably help if you specified which sense of "history" you are talking about here. History has many meanings and usages. "That is history" is a very specific usage.

Comment: @EddieKal history - what is past.

Comment: It's grammatical, but people don't say *It's story now* to mean that a thing is now a thing of the past.

Comment: Is it possible the dictionary is explaining the use of **story** in  questions like "What's *his* story?" which could be paraphrased as "What is his past?" or "Tell me about what experiences he's undergone that have made him behave how he does".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm interpreting the "for instance" as an example sentence SovereignSun made up themselves to illustrate a potential use case. It's not a "I've seen this - is it correct?" question, but instead a "From my limited knowledge of what this word means, I think I could create new sentences like this. Would I be correct in doing so?"   -- I might ask SovereignSun to better reference the sources for the quoted definitions, but I don't think ELL should be limited to only "How to correctly read English" questions. "How to correctly write English" should be on topic, too.

Comment: @R.M.: I don't disagree with your general point there, but I think in this specific case it's relevant that the OP is actually quite competent in English. He's *answered* twice as many questions as he's *asked* in almost 2 years on the site, and during that time he will have seen countless cases where a Google Books search has been used to quantify "native speaker preference" in contexts where only one of multiple superficially synonymous alternatives is actually idiomatic. So *in this specific case*, I'm inclined to think that background check could and should have been made by OP, not me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In respect to you, I've done the check. I say that I hardly always believe what Google says, so in case Google doesn't tell me what I wish to know, I ask here.

Comment: You give the lie to my earlier point! It's *I say that I **hardly ever** believe what Google says*, not ***hardly always*** :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, to answer your question bluntly.

**Those ideas are history now**. [That's the idiomatic expression: to be history].

History has many stories to tell. In fact, much of history are accounts (or stories) told my historians or by people who have experienced some aspect of it. Some are true, others not.

- The whole story of the JFK assassination is not yet known.
- His war stories [accounts of what happened to him] are inspiring.

Comment: Agreed.  Note that in these usages 'story' is a countable noun, and 'history' is not.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that you can't use "story" as you're trying to, be aware of ["storied"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/storied):

> 1 : decorated with designs representing scenes from story or history a
>   storied tapestry
>
> 2 : having an interesting history : celebrated in
>   story or history a storied institution

In a stretch, you might be able to use "Those ideas are storied now".  But be prepared to clarify what you mean.